# Cannot construct object

Tags: c++, c++11

I spend last two hours trying to figure out why the following code won't compile and I got nothing. Relevant parts of my code follows (full code is here http://pastebin.com/z78iy3AA (hpp) and http://pastebin.com/5mC6TwET (cpp) here if needed):

```
/*
File: du1simd.hpp
*/

#include <iterator>
#include <cstdint>
#include <new>

template< typename T, typename S>
class simd_vector;

template<typename T, typename S>
class simd_vector_iterator
    : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T> {
    typedef
        typename simd_vector<T, S>::iterator
        self_type;
    typedef
        typename std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>::pointer
        pointer;
    typedef
        typename std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>::reference
        reference;
    typedef
        typename std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>::value_type
        value_type;
    typedef
        typename
            std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>::difference_type
        difference_type;
 public:
    simd_vector_iterator()
        : ptr_(nullptr) {}
    explicit simd_vector_iterator(pointer ptr)
        : ptr_(ptr) {}
    explicit simd_vector_iterator(const self_type & other)
        : ptr_(other.ptr_) {}
    explicit simd_vector_iterator(self_type && other)
        : ptr_(other.ptr_) {
        other.ptr_ = nullptr;
    }

    /*
    Operators for random access iterator are here
    */

 private:
    pointer ptr_;
};

template< typename T, typename S>
simd_vector_iterator< T, S>
operator+(std::ptrdiff_t n, simd_vector_iterator< T, S> a) {
    return a += n;
}

template< typename T, typename S>
simd_vector_iterator< T, S>
operator-(std::ptrdiff_t n, simd_vector_iterator< T, S> a) {
    return a -= n;
}

template<typename T, typename S>
class simd_vector {
 public:
    typedef simd_vector_iterator<T, S> iterator;

    explicit simd_vector(std::size_t s) throw(std::bad_alloc) {
        pointer_to_allocated_memory_ =
            ::operator new(sizeof(T) * s + sizeof(S));

        uintptr_t pointer_to_allocated_memory =
            (uintptr_t) pointer_to_allocated_memory_;
        uintptr_t pointer_to_alligned_memory =
            pointer_to_allocated_memory + sizeof(S)
            - pointer_to_allocated_memory % sizeof(S);
        data_s_ = reinterpret_cast<S*>(pointer_to_alligned_memory);
        data_t_ = reinterpret_cast<T*>(pointer_to_alligned_memory);
    }

    ~simd_vector() {
        ::operator delete(pointer_to_allocated_memory_);
    }

    iterator begin() {
        iterator i(data_t_);
        return i;
    }

    iterator end() {
        /*...*/
    }

    std::size_t size() {
        return count_;
    }

    /*...*/

 private:
    void * pointer_to_allocated_memory_;
    std::size_t count_;
    S * data_s_;
    T * data_t_;
};
```

and the test code:

```
/*
File: du1simd.cpp
*/

#include "du1simd.hpp"

typedef int T;
struct S {
    T a, b, c;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    simd_vector<T, S> sv(5);
    *(sv.begin()) = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this, I see following error:

```
In file included from du1simd.cpp:8:0:
du1simd.hpp: In instantiation of ‘simd_vector<T, S>::iterator simd_vector<T, S>::begin() [with T = int; S = S; simd_vector<T, S>::iterator = simd_vector_iterator<int, S>]’:
du1simd.cpp:17:16:   required from here
du1simd.hpp:192:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘simd_vector_iterator<int, S>::simd_vector_iterator(simd_vector<int, S>::iterator&)’
         return i;
                ^
du1simd.hpp:192:16: note: candidate is:
du1simd.hpp:59:5: note: simd_vector_iterator<T, S>::simd_vector_iterator() [with T = int; S = S]
     simd_vector_iterator()
     ^
du1simd.hpp:59:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Which I think tells me I don't have appropriate constructor, I when I look at code of simd_vector_iterator I see constructor which (IMHO) matches the signature :/

Would anyone be so kind to help me with this?

DISCLOSURE: yes, this is a homework assigment. no, I don't want someone to finish it for me. I just need help with this "won't compile" situation.

Comment: +1 for the disclosure. This is the kind of "homework" question SO likes to see - one showing effort and attempts, and one which explains the sticking point clearly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS2013 throws the following error, which has a better message:

> error C2558: class 'simd_vector_iterator' : no copy constructor
>   available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'

Removing the `explicit` keyword on your copy constructor should be enough:

```
simd_vector_iterator(const self_type & other) : ptr_(other.ptr_) {}
```

Comment: I just figured this on my own, it solves my problem. I was to fixed on "constructor with one argument should be explicit" :D. Thank you for your effort, accepting this as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you constructed your iterator correctly in `begin()`, but when you return `i`, a copy needs to be made. As a consequence, the compiler wants to use the copy constructor (`simd_vector_iterator(const simd_vector_iterator&)`, which does not exist.

A solution can be to add a default copy constructor:

```
simd_vector_iterator(const simd_vector_iterator&) = default;
```

Comment: but constructor with this signature is already in there, simd_vector_iterator(const self_type &) ...

Comment: @Paladin Your original copy ctor was not the same since it was marked explicit. Therefore this is a correct answer

Comment: no exactly, I tried to add your line, but compiler throwed new error about not being able to overload.. since constructor with this signature was already there. removing the "explicit" solved it.

Comment: @Paladin sorry, I did not see the copy constructor before answering, its early here :-)

Comment: @const_ref can you explain why `explicit` prevents from constructing the iterator by copy?

Comment: @piwi An explicit constructor constructs objects just like non-explicit constructors, but does so only where the direct-initialization syntax or where casts are explicitly used. Calling simd_vector<T, S> sv(5) involves copy-initialization, not direct-initialization, and thus should be an error

Comment: @const_ref that was actually pretty obvious; I should go back to sleep. Thanks anyway!